# Is it possible to connect a MIPI CSI-2 deserializer to SC206E with CSI-1 interface

Tags: camera, csi, mipi

I am interfacing a [deserializer](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds90ub960-q1.pdf?ts=1700721811581&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)[DS90UB960-Q1] with Quectels [smart module](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-sc206e-smart-module-series)[SC206E].

The deserializer supports MIPI CSI-2 and SC206E supports CSI-1.

May I know CSI-2 is backward compatible or not.

I have seen a [question similar to this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565062/is-it-possible-to-connect-csi-2-camera-to-csi-1-port).But it is closed. Don't know why.

EDIT:1

It was a mistake by Quectel AE team,that they told us [SC206E] won't support CSI-2.

Today we received the information from Quectel R&D team that [SC206E] supports CSI-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I know CSI-2 is backward compatible or not.

There can be device-specific compatibility but the standards/specs do not specify backwards compatibility *(Tom Carpenter says exactly the same thing in his comment under the closed topic you linked)*. Even different versions of CSI-2 (e.g. CSI-2 v3.0 and CSI-2 v2.0) do not guarantee inter-compatibility although there could be some devices supporting, for example, CSI-2 v3.0 and all previous versions.

Some devices might be compatible so it's better to ask the component manufacturers or their application engineers.